Question about a proof that one of $\root n\of{z_1\dots z_n}$ lie in the same disk as them
When reading problem 13. (Romania TST 2004) in the file pre-mop-black-4-26-15.tex:

Let $D$ be a closed disk in the complex plane. Prove that for all positive integers $n$, and for all complex numbers $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n\in D$  there exists a $z\in D$ such that $z^n = z_1z_2\cdots z_n$.

I have a question about the solution in this file:

Suppose the $z_j$ are all nonzero.
First we address the $n=2$ case; WLOG assume $z_1z_2=1$, so we want to show that for any $z\ne0$ and disk $D$ containing $z,1/z$, one of $\pm1$ must lie in $D$. Note that any such $D$ must contain a smaller $D'$ with $z,1/z$ on its boundary. If $z\in\mathbb{R}$, $\operatorname{sgn}(z)\in\{1,-1\}$ must always lie in $D'\subseteq D$. Otherwise, the identity $\frac{z-1}{1/z-1}\big{/}\frac{z+1}{1/z+1} = -1$ tells us that $z,1,1/z,-1$ form a harmonic quadrilateral, whence the segments from $z$ to $1/z$ and $-1$ to $1$ must intersect. In particular, if $D'$ is not the circumcircle of $z,1,1/z,-1$, it must contain exactly one of $1,-1$ in its interior, so we're done.
Now suppose $n\ge 3$ and WLOG assume $z_1z_2\cdots z_n = 1$. The key is that for any two indices $j,k$, the $n=2$ case gives us a geometric mean $z_{j,k}$ of $z_j,z_k$ with $z_{j,k}\in D$ and $|z_{j,k}| = \sqrt{|z_j|\cdot |z_k|}$. Call this $z_j,z_k\mapsto z_{j,k},z_{j,k}$ operation $T_{j,k}$; then there exists an infinite sequence $(j_1,k_1),(j_2,k_2),\ldots$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a positive integer $N(\epsilon)$ such that  for all positive integers $N\ge N(\epsilon)$ and indices $j$, $2^{-\epsilon} \le |z_j^{(N)}| \le 2^{\epsilon}$. (Here $z_j^{(N)} = (T_{j_N,k_N}\circ T_{j_{N-1},k_{N-1}}\circ \cdots \circ T_{j_1,k_1}) (z_j)$.)
To finish, let $c\in\mathbb{C}$ and $r\ge0$ denote the center and radius of $D$, respectively. For each $\epsilon>0$ and $N\ge N(\epsilon)$, we have $z_1^{(N)}\cdots z_n^{(N)} = 1$, so there must exist two roots of unity $\omega_1 = \omega_1^{(N)},\omega_2 = \omega_2^{(N)}$ and indices $j,k$ such that (the arguments of) $z_j^{(N)},\omega_1,z_k^{(N)},\omega_2$ run counterclockwise in that order. But if we let $z'_j = z_j^{(N)}/|z_j^{(N)}|$ and $z'_k = z_k^{(N)}/|z_k^{(N)}|$, then
$$\tag1 |c-z'_j| \le |c-z_j^{(N)}| + |z_j^{(N)} - z'_j| \le r + \left||z_j^{(N)}| - 1\right| \le r + (2^\epsilon-1). $$Yet $z'_j,\omega_1,z'_k,\omega_2$ lie in that order on the unit circle, so a similar argument to that of the $n=2$ case shows that at least one of $|c-\omega_1|,|c-\omega_2|$ is bounded above by $r+(2^\epsilon - 1)$ ("close" to $D$).
Hence for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $n$th root of unity at most distance $2^\epsilon - 1$ from $D$. Since there are only finitely many such roots and $\lim_{\epsilon\to0} 2^\epsilon - 1 = 0$, one of the $n$th roots of unity must lie in $D$, as desired.

In equation (1), I know that $|c-z_j^{(N)}|\le r$ is because $z_j^{(N)}\in D$, because $z_j\in D$ by assumption, and stays in $D$ after each operation, so $z_j^{(N)} = (T_{j_N,k_N}\circ T_{j_{N-1},k_{N-1}}\circ \cdots \circ T_{j_1,k_1}) (z_j)$ stays in $D$.
Can you explain the argument in the next sentence “Yet $z'_j,\omega_1,z'_k,\omega_2$ lie in that order on the unit circle, so a similar argument to that of the $n=2$ case shows that at least one of $|c-\omega_1|,|c-\omega_2|$ is bounded above by $r+(2^\epsilon - 1)$ ("close" to $D$).”
I know that $z'_j,\omega_1,z'_k,\omega_2$ run counterclockwise on the unit circle, and $|c-z'_j|,|c-z'_k|$ is bounded above by $r+(2^\epsilon - 1)$, but how to deduce that at least one of $|c-\omega_1|,|c-\omega_2|$ is bounded above by $r+(2^\epsilon - 1)$ ?

Is it using the fact that:

If $z'_j,\omega_1,z'_k,\omega_2$ run counterclockwise on the circle, and $c$ is a random point, then $\min(|c-\omega_1|,|c-\omega_2|)\le\max(|c-z'_j|,|c-z'_k|)$?

Is this a standard fact about the distance from a point to four points in counterclockwise order on the circle?
